# Trick testdisk to try to recover unrecoverable ntfs-partition

Tags: ntfs

I accidentally (too less sleep) formatted a ntfs partition (system-partition of windows 7) that I actually wanted to clone with imagex (yes, you may laugh at me).
If that wasn't enough, I first forgot to use the /q-switch for quick-format, canceled at 7% and formatted it again using the /q-switch.

I then tried to recover it using testdisk. After scanning the harddisk, it says that it can't recover my partition. Is there any possibility to trick testdisk for at least a partial recovery of that partition?

(btw: please do not mark this as dupe. I know how to recover files and in fact photorec would work. But it is important to recover the partition at least partially. So this is not a simple "recover files from deleted ntfs-partition"-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your file-system is lost (i.e. you killed it twice). the way that file recovering works is it looks for areas that are marked as unused, or marked for deletion or whatever. you just removed that information, and the structure that you now want to save. Don't think you can recover half a filesystem and if if you could it would not be meaningful (how good is a word file with every other character junk?).

Comment: thanks... finally i tried to recover the files with photorec. I don't know if every file was recovered, but I think I have nearly all.

Comment: -1 Doing a simple quick format doesn't affect disk data... There are other tools to **testdisk** that can recover it as well. **GetDataBack** being one of them.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik, It is not about affecting the disk data (the folders stored etc) he wants to recover the filesystem (MFT). That part of the disk IS wiped during a format.

Comment: @RobertKoritnik A quick format does not. However, he did not do a quick format. With Windows 7, this means up to 7% of the partition has been overwritten by 0x00. Recovery is now impossible.